# connect to IB TWS through matlab

Tags: matlab, tws

I have been trying to connect to interactive broker TWS through Matlab. I have Matlab version R2013b installed. I have installed IB TWS and its API on my computer. but when I try to connect to TWS using the command

```
ib = ibtws('', 7496);
```

It gives me the following error

> Error using COM.TWS_TwsCtrl_1/connect Error: Type mismatch, argument 4
>
> Error in ibtws (line 45)

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem after upgrading my server to Windows Server 2012 from 2008 and reinstalling all software - I solved it by NOT installing the latest IB TWS API ActiveX component, but the previous version from 2013.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the cross-platform IB-Matlab product, which is Java-based (not ActiveX):

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ib-matlab

IB-Matlab doesn't have such bugs, it is very reliable.